# Is $\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}A^n\right)v=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}(A^nv)$?

Tags: matrices

> Suppose we have a convergent power series of matrices
>   $$A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nX^n,$$
>   for $X\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Is it true that if $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then
>   $$Av=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(X^nv)?$$
>   If no, under what conditions is it true?

I am asking this question because I am trying to prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $e^\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\exp(A)$. Indeed, if $Av=\lambda v$ then
$$\exp(A)v=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}A^n\right)v\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}(A^nv)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\lambda^nv=e^\lambda v.$$
But I am not sure if the second equality is justified. Otherwise, we can try to show that
$$\det(\exp(A)-e^\lambda I)=0,$$
but this seems much harder.

Comment: Is convergence defined here in terms of the operator norm,I assume?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Yes.

Comment: Please always include some English words in the title, so that on right-clicking the title, the usual context menu of the browser will not be overridden by MathJax's context menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\sum\limits_{n\geq0}X_n$ denotes the limit of $\sum\limits_{n\geq0}^kX_n$ as $k\to\infty$. Since matrix multiplication is continuous, this means that $\bigl(\sum\limits_{n\geq0}X_n\bigr)v$ is the limit of $$\bigl(\sum\limits_{n\geq0}^kX_n\bigr)v\tag{1}$$ as $k\to\infty$.

On the other hand, $\sum\limits_{n\geq0}X_nv$ denotes the limit of $$\sum_{n\geq0}^kX_nv\tag{2}$$ as $k\to\infty$.

Check that both sequences (1) and (2) are in fact the same.